# Update site name in disclaimer

Tags: bug, status-completed, redefining-health

The [disclaimer page](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/disclaimer) in the help center appears to show an older name for the site:

> The information, advice, links and/or any other materials (“Content”) made available through **Health Stack Exchange** (the “Site”) are for informational purposes only and are not a substitute for professional medical advice, diagnosis, treatment or consultation.

[Looks like](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/530/) this needs to be elevated to the SE team?

Comment: Good catch. We will get it taken care of.

Comment: The disclaimer has been updated to reflect the new name. If you find any other instances please notify us of those as well.

Comment: @JohnP Cool! Happy to help!